# How to use any one of multiple filters in route in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am developing my application in Laravel 4.2. I have 2 filters in my application named `guest` and `admin`. Admin can access to all controllers and guest can access to only few controllers.

This is the route for admin

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'admin'), function() 
{
    \\controller functions
});
```

But I want to route functions for guest. I tried in this way

```
 Route::group(array('before' => 'admin'|'guest'), function() 
    {
        \\some controller functions
    });
```

But this type routing checks for both filters... But I need to check the user is `Admin or Guest` How will i configure the route? Can anyone help??

Comment: What do you want to achive with the second version? As I understand, if *it's guest or admin, do these*. It's the same if you not add any filter.

Comment: if I didn't add any filter, then how will I restrict the fucntions to specific users??

Comment: What means specific users?

Comment: Admin and Guest are two type of users.... Admin is able to access all functions ... but guest user is restricted to access some of these functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make third filter, that will check if user is guest or admin, for example the name is guestOrAdmin.
Than write a code like this:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'guestOrAdmin'), function() 
{
    \\all your controller functions which can be accessed by guests and admins
     Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'), function() 
    {
        \\some controller functions which can be access only by guest
    });
  Route::group(array('before' => 'admin'), function() 
    {
        \\some controller functions which can be access only by admin
    });
});
```